# Chrome for Android shows black box for HTML5 video elements

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, video

I'm trying to have a video on my site act like a gif would: No controls, just autoplays on page load.
However, on android it shows as a black box. Enabling controls via attribute does let the user play it by clicking on it, however that's not how I want it to act.

I tried mp4, webm, both and in both orders, with type attributes or not.
Playing it on page load or after the video's done loading doesn't work either.

**HTML:**

```
<video id="video" autoplay loop>
    <source src="img/prodotti.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="img/prodotti.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

**JS:**

```
video = document.getElementById('video');
video.load();
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
   video.play();
}, false);
```

---

tl;dr | Is there any way to make HTML5 video elements behave like gifs aka autoplay without controls nor any kind of user input on Chrome for Android?

Comment: autoplay is explicitly blocked by most mobile browsers to avoid racking up large bills for users on metered connections.

Comment: So I'm guessing I should fallback to gifs on mobile

Comment: I believe there has to be a way around the autoplay block, because I go to sites on mobile where the video autoplays without my interaction.